# Toggle Embed Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, embed, toggle

I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to have an embedded object loop or no longer loop after current play, by clicking a link/image. I need it to NOT change the page, so the current song keeps playing.

So far, I've tried using a Javascript GetElementByName to set loop=true/false, while it's default is currently set to true.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="To be implimented"><IMG ID=mode SRC=repeat.gif HEIGHT=22 onclick="PlayerMode()">
<script type="text/javascript">

var L=0;
function PlayerMode()
  {
  if(L==0){
  document.getElementById("playmode").loop="true"
  document.getElementById("mode").src="repeat.gif";
  L++;
  }

  else{
  document.getElementById("playmode").loop="false"
  document.getElementById("mode").src="repeatoff.gif";
  L--;
  }}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link to trigger JavaScript but not change the page afterwards, make sure your `onclick` code returns `false`. Also using a simple '"#"' as the link's `href` will avoid any undesired effects or error messages in case JavaScript is disabled or not supported (for whatever reason).

```
<a href="#" onclick="PlayerMode(); return false;">...</a>
```

As an alternative, you could as well keep your code and let your function call `return false;` at the end (see last snipped as well):

```
<a href="#" onclick="PlayerMode();">...</a>
```

Some further optimization, I'd use the following code (saves you using a global variable):

```
function toggleLoop() {
    var player = document.getElementById('playmode');
    document.getElementById('mode').src = (player.loop = !player.loop) ? 'repeat.gif' : 'repeatoff.gif';
    return false;
}
```

Note that in your current code `L` should have an initial value of `1` considering the player loops already. Otherwise you'd essentially enable looping on your first click (which won't change anything).

Comment: Thanks, but from the sounds of what you're saying, you're just telling me a way to improve my current coding, under the assumption it works: My problem is that this code DOES NOT work, and I'm looking for a way if possible TO make it work without a page refresh.

I know there is probably a couple ways to do it WITH a page refresh, but I tried this way, and it doesn't work: the loop setting stays the same, even though the other command (Img swap) executes properly.

Reason I don't want a page refresh is because it works the embed off a random INT on page load.

Comment: Just tried my code and it works (tried it with HTML5's `<audio>` and `<video>` tag). If it still doesn't work, your error is somewhere else (do you hear the file playing and just the looping/not looping is broken?). Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Using Firefox, and I'm not using an Audio or Video tag: I have it as EMBED, as stated previously.

Comment: Ah, so you're using an object tag? Okay, thought you've got it embedded using HTML5. Any specific plugin?

Comment: One additional thing that perhaps should be noted is I have to use the player inside a PHP 'echo' for other functions I use. I don't know the audio tag to use it... >_< I'm assuming it used flash player to play the mp3/m4a's by default.

The code you gave me wouldn't even change the image, even after fixing the quotations to not conflict. Currently, my problem is that the image will swap, but the embedded player will continue to play the song on it's original setting, even with the image swap working. I'm somewhat assuming that's because the 'loop' property is only accessed on load by default.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. You might be able to access some specific runtime specific method or attribute exposed by the plugin. As for HTML5's audio tag: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp

Comment: So using the audio tag, you actually waited, and saw that it would toggle loop on and off, and actually stop the player at the end of the song when used, if it started originally as 'loop=true'? Because I don't mind changing it.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly fine for me (used a 1s long sample); you might have to call `play()` as well, if you stopped it before though.

Comment: Could you please edit your description to include  what you did to make it work? I tried adapting what that page said, but it didn't play anything for me... Thanks :)

Comment: I've been playing with it and noticed there seems to be a problem with Firefox (actually all Gecko-based web browsers up to Firefox 13.0.1 it seems) to properly load mp3s from the audio source tag.
It will either not show the controls at all, or will show them but still not do anything when you click play.

Thanks for the attempts to help, but this remains unresolved until a fix for this has been found: MP3s were supposedly supported since Firefox 9, and all OGGs work fine, and I've tried demos from other sites. Gecko-exclusive program, Chrome works still, so this still partially helps.